# The metric on the space of continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces, function-spaces

Suppose that $G$ is an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and $(\Omega,d)$ is a complete metric space then designate by $C(G,\Omega)$ the set of all continuous functions from $G$ to $\Omega$.

The natural question is that how can we define the metric on $C(G,\Omega)$.

In Conway's book (GTM 11), he exhausts $G$ by a sequence of compact sets, i.e.$G=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_n$ where each $K_n$ is compact and $K_n\subset \operatorname{int} K_{n+1}$, and define
$$
\rho _n\left( f,g \right) =\sup\left\{ d\left( f\left( z \right) ,g\left( z \right) \right) :z\in K_n \right\} 
$$
for all functions $f$ and $g$ in $C(G,\Omega)$. Also define
$$
\rho \left( f,g \right) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( \frac{1}{2} \right) ^n\frac{\rho _n\left( f,g \right)}{1+\rho _n\left( f,g \right)}}
$$

I wonder that why not define the metric on $C(G,\Omega)$ by
$$
\rho \left( f,g \right) =\sup\left\{ d\left( f\left( z \right) ,g\left( z \right) \right) :z\in G \right\} .
$$
Are there any particular advantages to the metric defined by the authors?

In fact, I suspect that the metric defined by the second method is not complete. But I can't think of a good example to illustrate this point.

Comment: Your $\Omega$ might not be bounded, so simply taking $\sup$ might not give you a real number

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes，Thank you！

Comment: @ArcticChar - allowing a metric to take on $\infty$ as a value is not a significant drawback, or you can define $\rho(f,g) = \min\{1, \sup d(f,g)\}$, which induces the same topology. And since uniform convergence preserves continuity, zik2019 you are mistaken about it not being complete. However, that does not mean it generates the same topology as Conway's metric. You will have to see what use Conway makes of the metric to determine if yours would be suitable to replace it.